# Python: what is the fastest / most elegant way to see if every number in two arrays is the same?

Tags: python

ie, compare:

```
1,-1,1
```

to

```
1.0,-1, 1
```

should be the same

```
print("the input and the output are " + ( (input == calc_out) ? "the same" : "not the same"))
```

but it give a lexical error =\

Comment: Did you actually try using `==`?

Comment: The question isn't specific enough - what exactly are you hoping as output?

Comment: If you post the code for your best attempt at a solution, you will likely receive relevant answers in minutes.

Comment: Is `1,2,3` the same as `3,2,1`? If so, that's quite different.

Comment: no... just in my example, there could be decimals... but.. they are in the same order =\

Comment: Python doesn't have a ternary `?` operator. Instead, try `print ("the same" if input == calc_out else "different")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs indicate [various ways](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#comparing-sequences-and-other-types/) you can compare sequences and other types:

```
(1, 2, 3)              < (1, 2, 4)
[1, 2, 3]              < [1, 2, 4]
'ABC' < 'C' < 'Pascal' < 'Python'
(1, 2, 3, 4)           < (1, 2, 4)
(1, 2)                 < (1, 2, -1)
(1, 2, 3)             == (1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
(1, 2, ('aa', 'ab'))   < (1, 2, ('abc', 'a'), 4)
```

So for your example:

```
C:\Users\jon>python
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79096, Mar 19 2010, 21:48:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> [1,-1,1] == [1.0,-1,1]
True
```

Answer (score 3):

`==`

Answer (score 0):

found it... Python does Ternary weird:

```
print("the input and the output are " + ( "the same" if (input == calc_out)  else "not the same"))
```